# How to JOIN with one distinct column in one and multiple in the other?

Tags: sql, join

Here are the two sample tables (Issues and Users):

```
╔═════════════╦══════════╗
║ reporter_id ║ agent_id ║
╠═════════════╬══════════╣
║ asdf        ║ jfid     ║
║ asde        ║          ║
║ djij        ║ dije     ║
╚═════════════╩══════════╝
╔══════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║  id  ║ first_name ║ last_name ║
╠══════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║ asdf ║ Magnus     ║ Nilsson   ║
║ sdfe ║ Thomas     ║ Keller    ║
║ dije ║ Daniel     ║ Humm      ║
╚══════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Desired result:

```
╔═════════════╦══════════╦══════════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ reporter_id ║ agent_id ║ agent_first_name ║ agent_last_name ║ reporter_first_name ║ reporter_last_name ║
╠═════════════╬══════════╬══════════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║ asdf        ║ idfj     ║ john             ║ lee             ║ david               ║ lee                ║
║ aiej        ║          ║ mike             ║ dee             ║                     ║                    ║
║ isao        ║ idje     ║ sarah            ║ lee             ║ sarah               ║ dee                ║
╚═════════════╩══════════╩══════════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

What sort of join can handle this?  For context, this would be on Redshift (postgres).  I was thinking this...

```
select
    ??? 
from
    issues join users
        on issues.reporter_id = users.id AND issues.agent_id = users.id
```

I'm unclear on the select clause and I'm only marginally confident my from clause is correct.

Comment: if you're going to put random characters in fields, can you at least be consistent? they are different in every table! and in general, just join to the users table twice. once for the reporter, once for the agent

Answer (score 1):

You need to Join the `User` table twice. Also you desired result data doesn't match with the table data.

```
SELECT I.reporter_id, 
       I.agent_id, 
       U1.first_name AS agent_first_name, 
       U1.last_name  AS agent_last_name, 
       U2.first_name AS reporter_first_name, 
       U2.last_name  AS reporter_last_name 
FROM   issues I
       INNER JOIN users U2 
               ON U2.id = I.reporter_id 
       LEFT JOIN users U1 
              ON U1.id = I.agent_id
```

Comment: @JustCasual - No you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the same table twice. Just use a different alias, like this:

```
select
    issues.reporter_id
   ,issues.agent_id
   ,a.first_name as agent_first_name
   ,a.last_name as agent_last_name
   ,r.first_name as reporter_first_name
   ,r.last_name as reporter_last_name
from
    issues left join users r
        on issues.reporter_id = r.id 
    left join users a
        on issues.agent_id = a.id
```

Also, as you have null values for agent_id (and potentially for the reporter_id) you need to use left join